# Winrt BackgroundTask Executes

Tags: windows-runtime

When adding a background task in WinRT with a trigger of SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable
if the internet is available when the task is registered will if execute right then? or will the task wait for the internet to not be available and then available again to execute? 
Or can I force execution of that background task when my app is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backround task with `SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable` will only start when Internet becomes available. If it's already available when the task is registered, it won't trigger.

If you need to execute that code even if internet is available all the time, the best thing would be to create another background task with `TimeTrigger` and `SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable`. You are allowed to set it to the minimum interval of 15 minutes.

If you also need to be able to execute the same code from your app immediately, then put the relevant code in a separate library and call it both from the background tasks and the application code.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. I guess I will have to come up with a way to prevent the background task from running if the foreground task has run. I am trying to save locally then post to the server. I am worried what happens if my foreground save is in progress and then the user closes the app while I am in await from the server. and the task doesnt complete. Perhaps I am over thinking this